# How to save, retrieve, delete using JWT User data in HttpContext in .NET 6?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, jwt

I have an application which uses React frontend, .NET backend, and MongoDB database. I use the official MongoDB C# driver to communicate with the database. I have implemented basic authentication using JWTs (login, logout). I wrote some time ago a Starter Application, which uses the same authentication method as this application, the only difference being that there I use .NET's Identity, and EF Core. I also wrote an extension method for HttpContext, which retrieves some user information from the claims that are set after a user successfully logs in. Because now I do not use .NET's identity, when I call `HttpContext.GetCurrentUser()`, which is my extension method, I always get null as a response because the claims are not saved in login.

Relevant code excerpt:

```
Program.cs:

builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(o =>
            {
                o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                o.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                o.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(o =>
            {
                o.SaveToken = true;
                o.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
                o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidIssuer = jwtTokenConfig.Issuer,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(jwtTokenConfig.Secret)),
                    ValidAudience = jwtTokenConfig.Audience,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)
                };
            });

var app = builder.Build();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

```
AuthenticationController.cs

[HttpPost("login")]
public IActionResult Login([FromBody] LoginModel model)
{
    try
    {
       var user = _userRepository.GetUserByEmail(model.Email);

       if (user == null || !_cryptoService.CheckPassword(model.Password, user.HashedPassword))
                    return BadRequest("Emailul sau parola este greșită.");

       if (!user.EmailConfirmed)
           return BadRequest("Emailul nu este validat.");

       var jwtResult = _jwtAuthManager.GenerateJWT(user.Email, user);
       _userRepository.UpdateUserLastSignIn(user.Id);

       return Ok(new LoginResponseModel
       {
          Id = user.Id.ToString(),
          Email = user.Email,
          FirstName = user.FirstName,
          LastName = user.LastName,
          Location = user.MainLocation,
          AccessToken = jwtResult.AccessToken,
          RefreshToken = jwtResult.RefreshToken.TokenString
       });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       _errorLogRepository.AddErrorLog(ex.Message);

        return BadRequest("An unexpected error occured.");
     }           
}
```

```
JwtAuthManager.cs

public JwtAuthResult GenerateJWT(string username, User user, int? tokenDuration = null)
{
   var authClaims = new List<Claim>
   {
      new Claim(ClaimTypes.Sid, user.Id.ToString()),
      new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.Email),
      new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
      new Claim(type: "SubscriptionType", value: user.SubscriptionType),
      new Claim(type: "MainLocation", user.MainLocation),
      new Claim(type: "SubscriptionEndDate", user.SubscriptionEndDate.ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.Date)
   };

   return GenerateTokens(username, authClaims.ToArray(), DateTime.Now, tokenDuration);
}

public JwtAuthResult GenerateTokens(string username, Claim[] claims, DateTime now, int? tokenDuration = null)
{
   var shouldAddAudienceClaim = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(claims?.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Aud)?.Value);
   var jwtToken = new JwtSecurityToken(
                _jwtTokenConfig.Issuer,
                shouldAddAudienceClaim ? _jwtTokenConfig.Audience : string.Empty,
                claims,
                expires: now.AddMinutes(tokenDuration ?? _jwtTokenConfig.AccessTokenExpiration),
                signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(_secret), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature));
   var accessToken = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(jwtToken);

   var refreshToken = new RefreshToken
   {
      UserName = username,
      TokenString = GenerateRefreshTokenString(),
      ExpireAt = now.AddMinutes(_jwtTokenConfig.RefreshTokenExpiration)
   };

   _usersRefreshTokens.AddOrUpdate(refreshToken.TokenString, refreshToken, (s, t) => refreshToken);

   return new JwtAuthResult
   {
      AccessToken = accessToken,
      RefreshToken = refreshToken
   };
}
```

```
HttpContextExtensions.cs

public static class HttpContextExtensions
    {
        public static UserInfoModel GetCurrentUser(this HttpContext context)
        {
            var currentUser = context.User;
            if (!currentUser.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                return null;
            }

            var claims = ((ClaimsIdentity)currentUser.Identity).Claims;

            var claimsData = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            foreach (var claim in claims)
            {
                if (!claimsData.ContainsKey(claim.Type))
                {
                    claimsData.Add(claim.Type, claim.Value);
                }
            }

            var subEndDateHasValue = DateTime.TryParse(claims.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Type == "SubscriptionEndDate")?.Value, out DateTime subEndDate);

            return new UserInfoModel
            {
                Id = ObjectId.Parse(claimsData[ClaimTypes.Sid]),
                Email = claimsData[ClaimTypes.Email],
                MainLocation = claims.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Type == "MainLocation")?.Value,
                SubscriptionType = claims.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Type == "SubscriptionType")?.Value,
                SubscriptionEndDate = subEndDateHasValue ? subEndDate : null
            };
        }
    }
```

Sorry, for the big number of excerpts, I thought it might be useful for those as well who have the same problem in the future.

So in short my problem is: whether a user is logged in or not, when i call HttpContext.GetCurrentUser(), I get back null because context.User.Identity.isAuthenticated is always false, and also it doesn't have any claim set. I would like to get the User's information from this extension. Happy to answer any questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many days of tinkering, I found the issue. I had a completely wrong understanding how HttpContextAccessor works with .NET. I thought that the claims are saved by .NET's identity package, and when we call the current user we should be getting it. Welp, it was pretty naive of me to think this. You need to send the accessToken with your request in the header, and the HttpContext "decrypts" it.

If you have a react app as I did, add it as a header. In my case I use axios and like this it worked:

```
import axios from "axios";
import { ApplicationState } from "./rootReducer";
import store from ".";

const interceptor = () => {
    const local = "https://localhost:7025/api/";

    axios.interceptors.request.use(
        (conf: any) => {
            const state: ApplicationState = store.getState();
            let accessToken = state.auth.accessToken;

            conf.baseURL = local;
            conf.headers = {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`
            }
            return conf;
        }        
    )
}

export default {interceptor};
```